# search lucene on a specific document

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene with java to index some text documents. Now, after I get some top documents for a keyword search, I want to further refine my search and search only those top documents with some additional keywords, so each document once. Can somebody tell me on how I can search a specific document with a specific keyword, not the whole index, but lets say just 123.xml with keywords "bla blah".

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refine your search, you should use filters (look at IndexSearcher

```
search(Query query,
     Filter filter,
     int n,
     Sort sort)
```

)! Filters will be executed on the result set and are the proper way to implement refined searches.

Have a look at this page to find out how to use filters: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2009/02/filtering-a-lucene-search.html

Anyway:

If you want to search in just one document you can either take the one document, store it in a RAMDirectory and search in the RAMDirectory just as you would in your normal index. Or you can have a field containig unique identifyers for each document and add this to your query e.g. "contant:(bla blah) and uniqe_doc_id:(doc1)"

Comment: Im not very familiar with the lucene, could u give an example on how I would use the filter?